# QnaMakerDialog too many attempts

Tags: c#, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I developed a bot using pakage qna maker and I need to change the label for the tooManyAttempts ressource because in french it's not the best word used.
Can I change the ressource ? Or Can I tracked the tooManyAttempts var to change his value ?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: You added the [chatbot] tag, are you using [botframework]? Which tooManyAttemps label are you talking about, the one when you are selecting a value when several are matching?

Comment: Yes I use the botframework. I talking about that. I can not intercept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look to the implementation of `QnAMakerDialog` on Github ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L181)), you will find that the message is declared here:

```
protected virtual async Task QnAFeedbackStepAsync(IDialogContext context, QnAMakerResults qnaMakerResults)
{
    var qnaList = qnaMakerResults.Answers;
    var questions = qnaList.Select(x = >x.Questions[0]).Concat(new[] {
        Resource.Resource.noneOfTheAboveOption
    }).ToArray();

    PromptOptions < string > promptOptions = new PromptOptions < string > (
    prompt: Resource.Resource.answerSelectionPrompt, tooManyAttempts: Resource.Resource.tooManyAttempts, options: questions, attempts: 0);

    PromptDialog.Choice(context: context, resume: ResumeAndPostAnswer, promptOptions: promptOptions);
}
```

As you can see, the message sent when the `TooManyAttemptsException` is thrown is in the Resources of the package: `Resource.Resource.tooManyAttempts`.

You could think about overriding the method, but you will soon face the problem of having to reference undefined methods: here the `ResumeAndPostAnswer` is defined as private, so not visible.

So one of the solutions, sadly, would be to get all the necessary sources from the GitHub project (that is to say get almost all the QnAMakerDialog implementation)

Comment: So it's impossible to track this value ?

Comment: As I said, you can do it,but you have to get several classes from github to re-implement all the QnADialog on your side